# Yii Application works fine on localhost, but throws "not found" error on GoDaddy.com

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii, yii-url-manager

My Yii site works perfectly fine, when run on my laptop (localhost). But, when copied to GoDaddy.com and run from there, I'm getting following error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /website/Search_Best_Boat_Deals was not found on
>   this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache Server at
>   website.com Port 80

My `main.php` configuration file has the following configuration for URL management

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false, 
        'rules'=>array(

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

            'Search_Best_Boat_Deals'=>'site/vessels',


            '<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+>/'=>'site/Detailview',

            'message/inboxview/<messageId:[0-9]+>/'=>'message/inboxview',
            'message/view/<messageId:[0-9]+>/'=>'message/view',

            'message/sentview/<messageId:[0-9]+>/'=>'message/sentview',

            'message/compose/<id:[0-9]+>/<VesselId:[0-9]+>'=>'message/compose',
            'Gallery/ajaxUpload/gallery_id/<gallery_id:[0-9]+>'=>'Gallery/ajaxUpload',

            'site/activate/key/<key:[0-9]+>/mail/<mail:[0-9]+>'=>'site/activate',



            ),
        ),
```

My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: `/website.com` should not be in the 404 error unless you have a sub folder called `website.com` in your web root, is that how you have structured it?

Comment: Yes thats right. but should it make an difference? and I actually didnt like that linux hosting makes a big deal about uppercase and lower case..  But how do I solve it now?

Comment: This is not yii related, you have uploaded website to wrong folder - this is clearly apache error. It means that request did not even reached index.php

Comment: You need to figure out where to put your index.php on GoDaddy. I have no idea of what their web root is. (www or public_html?) User defined? Also check if it works without `.htaccess`, `RewriteBase /` might not work on some hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guy! I appreciate all your help. The following in the .htaccess worked for me

```sh
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 IndexIgnore */*

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L] 
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

change order of rules.

It seems when accessing `/website/Search_Best_Boat_Deals` it resolved to `Search_Best_Boat_DealsController` and `actionIndex`.

try this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false, 
    'rules'=>array(
        'Search_Best_Boat_Deals'=>'site/vessels',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+>/'=>'site/Detailview',
        'message/inboxview/<messageId:[0-9]+>/'=>'message/inboxview',
        'message/view/<messageId:[0-9]+>/'=>'message/view',
        'message/sentview/<messageId:[0-9]+>/'=>'message/sentview',
        'message/compose/<id:[0-9]+>/<VesselId:[0-9]+>'=>'message/compose',
        'Gallery/ajaxUpload/gallery_id/<gallery_id:[0-9]+>'=>'Gallery/ajaxUpload',
        'site/activate/key/<key:[0-9]+>/mail/<mail:[0-9]+>'=>'site/activate',
        ),
    ),
```