# Redirection using Routing not working in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-routing

I have `ProjectsController.php` in which I have `actionIndex`

In my main.php file which is in `frontend/config/main.php` I have done routing as below.

```
 'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'projects'=>'projects/index',
         ],
       ],  
     ]
```

Which means I am trying to redirect to index action in projects controller with url `/projects`. I am able to access in my localhost like `localhost/myproject/projects`, but whereas when I try to access the same in live like `www.myproject/projects/` it is redirecting to home page and if I try to access like `www.myproject/frontend/web/projects/index` then I am able to redirect to the correct page.Not only this particular action and controller, all the other routing mentioned in main.php are redirecting to home page.

Below is my `.htaccess` file code in my root file '/'

```
    # prevent directory listings
#Options -Indexes
#IndexIgnore */*

# follow symbolic links
#Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/common/css/
#RewriteRule ^common/css/(.*)$ common/css/$1 [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*/web/)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
#RewriteRule .* backend/web/index.php [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*/web/)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/web/
#RewriteRule backend/(.*)$ backend/web/index.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^frontend/(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^common/(.*)$      common/$1   [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^frontend/images/(.*)$      frontend/images/$1   [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      frontend/web/index.php/$1   [QSA,L,NC] 

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^frontend/(assets|css|js|images|themes)
#RewriteRule ^frontend/images/(.*)$      frontend/images/$1   [QSA,L,NC]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web/projects/$
#RewriteRule frontend/projects/(.*)$ frontend/web/index.php/projects/$ [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*/themes/)

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|js|images|themes|uploads)
#RewriteRule ^themes/(.*)$ backend/web/themes/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ backend/images/$1
#RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]



#RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ backend/themes?$ [L,PT]
#RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
#
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/(assets|css|themes)/
#RewriteRule .* backend/themes/$1 [L]  

#Options -Indexes
#RewriteEngine on


#
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
#RewriteRule frontend/web(.*) frontend/web/index.php [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images|themes)
#RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^themes/(.*)$ frontend/web/themes/$1 [L]
```

Below is the `.htaccess` from `/frontend/web/`

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Please help. I am unable to resolve this. I am actually not able to understand the cause.

Comment: what server you are using ?

Comment: What is the path of your .htaccess file? Do you have urlManager component in your common/main.php file also?

Comment: @MAZ No, I do not have urlManager in common/main.php The .htacces code which I have mentioned above is from my root file i.e '/'. Also I have edited my query and added .htacces file of frontend/web/.htaccess

Comment: @KandarpPatel I am using godaddy server

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two `.htaccess`. One in your project root folder and another in your `frontend/web` folder.

Please follow the steps of Anant Singh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239858/yii2-pretty-urls-are-formed-but-not-working-says-404-not-found) of this question.

[Yii2:-Pretty URL's are formed, but not working (says 404 “NOT FOUND”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239858/yii2-pretty-urls-are-formed-but-not-working-says-404-not-found)

I hope It will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      frontend/web/index.php/$1   [QSA,L,NC]
```

Change above rule in your root .htaccess to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      frontend/web/$1   [L,NC]
```

Comment: is it the godaddy shared hosting ?

Comment: well in that case. seems this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736282/yii-application-works-fine-on-localhost-but-throws-not-found-error-on-godaddy